# Adding items to a List(Of) during for loop VB

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I am trying to add each numeric digit in a textbox to a list(of Integer) but I am required to use integer.Parse to get it into the correct format, but upon doing so  receive a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.
My code is as follows:

```
Dim key As List(Of Integer)
Dim digit As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
        digit = Integer.Parse(c)
        key.Add(digit)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim` only declares that you want a variable named `key` to be a `List(of Int32)`.  it does not create the collection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize an instance of the list. This is done using the `New` keyword:

```
Dim key As New List(Of Integer)
```

**Read more about the [`New` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx)**